# vector is returning a size() of 0

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++ programming and I am having trouble with the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Absolute {

    public: 
        vector<int> nums;

        Absolute(vector<int> nums) { 
            nums = nums; //<--- this size is not 0
        }

        vector<int> getNums() { return nums; }

        int addr() { 
            int total = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++) { //<--- nums.size() here is 0 even though it should not be 
                total += nums[i];
            }

            return total;
        }

};
    
int main() {

    vector<int> numbers = {1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}; //<--- passing this to addNums but still returns size of 0
    Absolute addNums = Absolute(numbers);

    cout << addNums.addr() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to add up all the numbers in the `vector` together using the `addr()` method, but for some reason the size of the `vector` is 0 inside of the `addr()` method, so I end up printing these very large numbers:

```
15152333321
```

What is going on here? Could it be that it's not being initialized with the `vector` in the first place?

Comment: You might want to name your **parameter** something different from your **member variable**.  `nums = nums;` just sets the parameter to the value of the parameter.

Comment: Or just use a constructor member-initializer list.

Comment: Best to do both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this code:

```
Absolute(vector<int> nums)
{
    nums = nums; 
}
```

You encounter what I call "Highlander's Law" ([There can be only one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs)). In this function, `nums` refers to the parameter `nums`, not the member `nums`. The member `nums` is [shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), hidden, by the parameter. So `nums = nums;` means assign the parameter to itself. The member `nums` is unchanged and stays at size 0.

Fix: You can change the name of one of the variables so that they do not collide. You can be extra explicit with `this->nums = nums`, but there's a better and faster option: Use the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) and initialize the member `nums` with the correct value rather than initialize it to a default and then assign it.

```
Absolute(vector<int> nums): nums(nums)
{
}
```

You can use the same name here because there is no ambiguity. The member `nums` is being initialized, so it must be the left-most `nums`. It is initialized to the parameter `nums` because the parameter is the current holder of the identifier `nums`.

Side note: Consider passing by reference and save yourself a copy:

```
Absolute(const vector<int> & nums): nums(nums)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @Eljay, you have the same name for your parameter and your member variable in *Absolute* constructor.

This change

```
        Absolute(vector<int> nums) { 
            this->nums = nums; //<--- this size is not 0
        }
```

should be enough for your example to work if you really want to keep the same name. I strongly suggest you to have a different name for your parameter, *_nums* for example.

Comment: `Absolute(vector<int> nums) : nums(nums) {}` would work without renaming (and be more efficient by avoiding default initializing the `vector` first). `Absolute(vector<int> nums) : nums(std::move(nums)) {}` to make it even more efficient.

Comment: I see, it is bad practice to use the same names for parameter and attributes? I come from python and my instructor mentioned you usually name them the same

Comment: @I.C.Wiener it is an OK practice if both you and your compiler can tell those things apart; if one of you gets confused - THAT's bad :)

Comment: I don't think it's *bad*. It's just a potential pitfall. Expert C++ coders can tell the difference, and I've seen good coders do it when there's no better name for the parameter (after all, oftentimes the *only* purpose of a constructor parameter is to be moved into a similarly-named instance variable)

Comment: @I.C.Wiener *I come from python* -- C++ is not python.  Do not use python (or any other language) as a model in writing C++ code.  If you keep going down that route, you wind up exactly where you were -- the program will not compile, or it will have bugs, or it will be inefficient.  And to top if off, the program will look weird to a C++ programmer -- you won't find too many C++ programmers naming their parameters the same as their member variables.

Comment: Often you'll find member variables are given a prefix or a suffix so that you can eliminate ambiguity. When you have, for example, a size, you'd be an idiot not to call it `size`, but you can't have two variables named `size` in the same scope. But if the member size is called `m_size`... zero ambiguity with minimal extra typing.